# Why are sperm cells not attacked by the female immune system?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, reproductive-biology

Whenever a foreign particle enters into someone's body, it is attacked by the white blood cells. I just want how it is that, when sperms enter the female body, they are not attacked by the the woman's immune system?

Answer (score 2):

Studies show semen does mount a considerable immune response in the female mucosa, however:

> Seminal plasma redirects the differentiation of human dendritic cells (DCs) toward a regulatory profile. By promoting a tolerogenic profile in DCs, seminal plasma might favor fertility, but might also compromise the capacity of the receptive partner to mount an effective immune response against sexually transmitted pathogens.

[Semen promotes the differentiation of tolerogenic dendritic cells.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23066152)